# Angularjs sorts data from Ajax call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, sorting, mean-stack

I am making an API call and the data is being sorted when I don't want it to be. The API looks like this:

```
{"AM Meetings/HR":{"starting-time":"8:00","end-time":"9:05"},"C":{"starting-time":"9:10","end-time":"10:35"},"Community":{"starting-time":"10:40","end-time":"11:25"},"D":{"starting-time":"11:30","end-time":"12:55"},"Lunch":{"starting-time":"13:00","end-time":"13:45"},"E":{"starting-time":"13:50","end-time":"15:15"}}
```

So, it goes AM Meetings/HR, C, Community, D, Lunch, and E. But, when I use this AngularJS call:

```
$scope.getCurrentDay = function(){
        $http.get("/api/currentDay/")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.currentDay = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
```

currentDay and the log show it as AM Meetings/HR, C, Community, D, E, Lunch, which is sorted Alphabetically.

Is there any way to make it not sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Can you change the response from API? Also they are not technically "sorted" as those keys would be encoded from JSON as object properties, for which no order is guaranteed during iteration. There is nothing preventing you from reading the objects at those keys into an array of your making and sorting that array as desired.

Comment: Objects are unsorted and the results are going to vary from browser to browser. If you need to maintain a sort order, you should be using an array instead (array of objects, sort via object key)